# hardhat tasks don't persist data on local network

Tags: reactjs, solidity, hardhat

I create a little NFT marketplace using solidity and hardhat. I have a JSON file with the NFT details and I wrote a hardhat task for automating the process.

```
task("populate-market", "populate market with nfts").setAction(async function (
  taskArguments,
  hre
) {
  const [owner] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
  const Market = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFTMarket");
  const market = await Market.deploy(owner.address);
  await market.deployed();
  const marketAddress = market.address;
  /* deploy the NFT contract */
  const Item = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Item");
  const nft = await Item.deploy(marketAddress);
  await nft.deployed();
  for (const item of nfts) {
    const transaction = await nft.createToken(item.url);
    const tx = await transaction.wait();
    const event = tx.events[0];
    const tokenId = event.args[2].toNumber();
    const price = hre.ethers.utils.parseUnits(item.price.toString(), "ether");
    await market.createMarketItem(nft.address, tokenId, price, item.supply);
  }
  console.log(await market.fetchMarketItems());
  console.log("done!");
});
```

the problem it's when I load the data in my react app; I created an function `getNfts()` like this:

```
 useEffect(() => getNfts(), []);
  const getNfts = async () => {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider();
    const nftContract = new ethers.Contract(NFT_ADDRESS, NFT.abi, provider);
    const marketContract = new ethers.Contract(
      MARKET_ADDRESS,
      Market.abi,
      provider
    );
    const data = await marketContract.fetchMarketItems();
    console.log(data);
  };
```

in this function `data` it returns empty array but, in task the `console.log(await market.fetchMarketItems());` it returns all nfts. I don't understand why in the task it returns data but, in react it shows me an empty array. How to fix this?

Comment: have you checked that you are deploying in the correct network and have the correct address?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```js
async function getNfts() {
  // The rest of the code goes here
}
```

Basically use a function instead a variable asigned to a function. Sometimes there are errors with the `this` keyword that are not being passed correctly and it breaks the functionality of the library.